# Libinput-gesture maximize/unmaximize and minimize window :: Wayland

Tags: gnome, touchpad, multi-touch, libinput, gestures

I use wayland and gnome 3.28.
I would like to set libinput so that a 4 finger swipe up maximize/unmaximize the currently active window, and a 4 finger swipe down minimize it.

I digged a bit and it looks like that xdotool doesn't work properly in a wayland session, so a command like this

> gesture swipe up 3 xdotool key super+Up

is ineffective.

Do you know how to get the aforementioned behaviour when performing 4 finger swipes on the touchpad?

Comment: have you tried ydotool? (https://github.com/ReimuNotMoe/ydotool)